# Auto-Resize Image to fill div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image inside of a div which I need to have as large as possible. I have tried using `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` and the same for `max-width` and `max-height` but that has not worked. The reason these are not working is because my images are various sizes, some tall and some wide. Is there a way to have the image resize so that it will be as wide as possible without having height extend the div?

Basically: `width:100%` unless that makes `height` greater than 100%, in which case I want to use `height:100%`.

Comment: If you need the image size limited by both the parent's height *and* width, you might consider using a background image and setting it's [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to "contain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the more elegant solutions is to set the size of the div, then set its background to `url(foo) cover`. This chops off the edges if need be. Using `contain` instead of `cover` does the same, but without chopping off the edges.

Edit: Per comments, I suggested using `object-fit: contain`. No need to downvote over my suggestion to use a background image.

Comment: Is an img element not a background.

Comment: You can use `object-fit: cover` or `contain` then. Regardless, images are frequently made backgrounds for logistical reasons.

Comment: You can't just assume an image is a background just because "images are frequently made backgrounds for logistical reasons."

Comment: The issue that I have is that this is for an ecommerce store. If these are background images then will my `:hover` effects still work? And I would have to reset the layout to make the links still effective. I am not sure `background-image` is the best choice.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize you were looking for other effects. Yes, using a regular image would be bet then. You can still use `object-fit: contain`.

Comment: This worked! My solution was `object-fit:contain`, this does not cut off the image and maximizes its size. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `object-fit: cover;` css rule for your image.

This is pretty much the equivalent of background-size: cover if you are working with backgrounds.

Be awere that the rule will "crop" parts of your image, depending on the ratio.

UPDATE:
If you don't want to crop anything from the image, you can just use `height:inherit;` and position you image somehow to fit all styles (perhaps center)

This will maintain the ratio and will expand the width as much as posible.

Comment: This would work, but I am using this for product images for a store, so cutting off parts of the image is not an option. `contain` may work as an alternative.

Comment: @JakeP I would recommend setting it as a background image, per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When either `width` or `height` is set (not both), the one that is not explicitly set will automatically adjust to keep the image in the correct proportion. All that is needed to have a responsive image (one that scales to its parent element's size) is to simply set **either** (not both) of the following:

```
width:100%;

height:100%;
```

And, of course, the parent element must also have a `width` or `height` that is responsive as well. If the parent can never resize, then the child won't ever resize.

To ensure that the `height` never gets bigger than a certain amount, that's when `max-height` would be used on the image or just `height` and `overflow` on the image container.

Here's an example:

```css
#container {
  display:flex;
}

div:not(#container){
  width:25%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden; /* ensure height is consistent */
}


/* Comment the following out temporarially to see the native image sizes */
img { 
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54e8ba93e4b07c3f655b452e/t/56c2a04520c64707756f4267/1493764650017/"></div>
 <div><img src="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cute-kittens-30-57b30ad41bc90__605.jpg"></div>
 <div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fa44expvfZrMe6nIG7n_7mblJJbI1FGaAJledcdzZjaLPzntm2rUWr2_4xxRXGadre41CdqyGHE=s640-h400-e365"></div>
 <div><img src="https://fthmb.tqn.com/INZEtkWYEpsZaksoewT_mA4DREo=/960x0/filters:no_upscale()/about/Two-kittens-GettyImages-559292093-58822e4f3df78c2ccd8b318c.jpg"></div>
 <div><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/w6DW4i-mfbA/hqdefault.jpg"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, but the problem I am having is that now my image is distorted because when it gets to be the `max-height` it still gets wider, just not taller. Any fix for that?

Comment: @JakeP Yes, if you look at my example, there's another way to limit the `height` without `max-height` and that is to set an absolute `height` on the container as well as `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: This leads to the image being cut off at the bottom when I implement it. I still need to see the entire image.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need the image to fill the div regardless of different  sizes right?

1. Give `<div>` container any **width** and **height** you want.
2. Give `<img>` elements **width:100%**.

> **height** will be adjusted automatically.

3. If you want images to wrap after each other use **display:flex** property on `<div>` container.

Comment: This has already been answered, although your answer does not work. This will make the image as wide as possible, but it does not account for tall images. If `height`>`width` then height should be 100%, not `width:100%`.